Armor takes up durability when regening health
So, I am trying to armor for a Roblox game, I made it DETECT when the player has health changed (Like damage), after fighting, the armor starts to take up durability when the player is regening health. Is the any idea how to fix this?
Here is the armor script:
local armor = script.Parent
repeat wait() until armor.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

local player =  game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(armor.Parent)
local dura = armor.Durability.Value
local max = armor.Max.Value

local damageReduction = 4
local regening = false

player.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid").HealthChanged:Connect(function()
    if dura > 0 and not regening then
        regening = true
    
        local dmgRecieved = player.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid").Health -     player.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid").MaxHealth
        print(math.abs(math.floor(dmgRecieved)))

        armor.ArmorHitSFX:Play()
        dura -= 1
    
        player.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid").Health += dmgRecieved/damageReduction
        wait(0.01)
        regening = false
    else
        armor:Destroy()
    end
end)`

And here is the tool activation:
local armor = script.Parent
repeat wait() until armor.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

local player =  game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(armor.Parent)

armor.Activated:Connect(function()
    player.PlayerGui.Stats.ArmorBackground.Visible = true
    
    local weld = Instance.new("WeldConstraint",armor.Handle)
    weld.Part0 = armor.Handle
    weld.Part1 = armor.Parent.Torso
    
    armor.Handle.Parent = player.Character
    armor:Destroy()
end)

This is running on a server side script, to make sure the armor actually breaks rather than leaving to on the player. I have tried to add a damage as a variable to make sure it only counted the damage, not when regening, but it still wouldn't work. There also seems to be no apparent tutorials on how to get rid of this problem but only showed how to disable regening, is there any way that I can fix this so I don't have to scrap this?

your code doesn't make any sense. first of all don't calculate damage from max health. You need to use players health before he received damage. Otherwise your damage values are way too high from the second hit. calculating damage and damage reduction when regenerating doesn't make sense.
calculate lasthealth - newhealth. if it is positive you're being healed. if it is negative you receive damage. only then use armor.  take pen and paper, draw a flow chart, do the maths with a few examples and think befor you start to code

Can you provide an example of what it should look like?
